How can I evaluate $1 / \Gamma (-1)$?
I understand intuitively that the Gamma function diverges at all negative integers. This leads me to believe that the inverse Gamma function would have zeros at all negative integers. However, I’m looking for a rigorous proof of this.
I’ve examined the functional equation that connects the Gamma function to the Riemann zeta function. I noticed that for negative integers, the sine component equates to zero. Here’s the functional equation I’m referring to:
$$
\zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s)
$$
Additionally, I’ve plotted the inverse Gamma function and observed that it indeed has zeros at the expected values (negative integers).
Could anyone provide a detailed proof or explanation for why the inverse Gamma function has zeros at all negative integers? Any insights or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Strictly speaking does the inverse not exist , but it is clear that if the value approaches $\infty$ or $-\infty$ , the inverse must approch $0$ since the gamma-function is continous.

The reciprocal gamma function is an entire function with simple zeros at the non-positive integers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function

The Gamma function satisfies the property $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ (for $x\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}_-$).
Therefore for $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}_-,\quad  \Gamma(x+2)=(x+1)x\Gamma(x)$ and $\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\underset{x\to -1}{\to} \frac{(-1+2)(-1+1)}{\Gamma(1)}=0$.
